# Cycling through parameters in a Delphi Recordset

Tags: mysql, delphi, parameters, recordset

I have a delphi datasource with a variable dataset. These datasets have a variable number of parameters. I want to be able to modify the values of all parameters in the dataset to a set value. I'm trying to iterate through all of the parameters in the set by using the .Items[] property of the parameters as below:

```
 with (datamoduleSearch.datasourceSearch.DataSet as TADODataSet) do
  begin
    Close;
    i := 0;
    while assigned(Parameters.Items[i]) do
    begin
      Parameters.Items[i].Value := SearchText;
      inc(i);
    end;
    Open;
    Active := True;
  end;
end;
```

However this fails as I suspect I'm not using the assigned procedure correctly. Is there any way to find the number of parameters in a recordset and iterate through it in the way I have described?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a for loop instead. You can also reference `Parameters[]` directly, as `Items` is the default property:

```
for i := 0 to Parameters.Count - 1 do
    Parameters[i].Value := SearchText;
```